# starting postgres server: creates 6 instances of postgres and stalls

Tags: postgresql

I am so extremely new to this so i apologize in advance if i'm asking a dumb question. Also, if possible, an extremely dumbed down answer would be most preferable.

Using a mac osx 10.8.4, have installed PostgreSQL 9.2.4 and psycopg2 with homebrew, and I'm trying to start my server using the command terminal told me to use after giving me the "success! PostgreSQL is installed" message.

so i ran:
    postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres/data

and terminal returned:

- LOG:  database system was shut down at 2013-08-09 13:38:46 EDT
- LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
- LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

and then it stops. I left it for a half hour and still nothing. Went to check activity manager and there are six instances of postgres running. Killed them all and started over, got the same result. Repeated this process countless times. Any help?

Comment: If I am not mistaken - the log shows, that postgres successfully started and `ready to accept connections`. Have you tried connecting to it with some client tools?

Comment: using pgAdmin3; I don't know how i would connect to it because i haven't set up a name or configured any other info... Also, is it normal for it to run 6 instances?

Comment: For database connection info - just google how homebrew sets default settings. As for 6 instances - yes, they have different purposes and roles in postgres server.

Comment: how do i give you points? lol

Comment: I added a full answer.

Comment: Once the server is started you must connect to it with a client like `psql` or `PgAdmin-III`. It doesn't have an interactive user interface. It's normal for many processes to start; see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_does_PostgreSQL_have_so_many_processes.2C_even_when_idle.3F .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
>   LOG: autovacuum
>   launcher started

Means that server successfully started and ready to accept connections.

As for 6 instances - yes, they have different purposes and roles in postgres server.

Comment: For the "many processes" question see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_does_PostgreSQL_have_so_many_processes.2C_even_when_idle.3F